# How to create a plotly figure factory subplots in python?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

Sample data

```
import seaborn as sns

sample = sns.load_dataset("tips")
```

Figure Factory plot

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
fig =  ff.create_table(sample.head())
fig.show()
```

[image]

I wanted to plot a `sample.head()` and `sample.tail()` side by side as a subplots with `create_table()`

How to plot subplots with `ff.create_table()` in plotly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using https://plotly.com/python/table/ and https://plotly.com/python/subplots/

Using sample data:

```
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

sample = sns.load_dataset("tips")

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=1,
    cols=2,
    specs=[[{"type": "table"} for _ in range(2)]],
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Table(
        cells={"values": sample.head().values.T}, header={"values": sample.columns}
    ),
    row=1,
    col=1,
)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Table(
        cells={"values": sample.tail().values.T}, header={"values": sample.columns}
    ),
    row=1,
    col=2,
)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to colour column headers and any single column using go.table?

Comment: yes, it's detailed here: https://plotly.com/python/table/

Comment: This shouldn't be marked as the accepted answer cause it doesn't answer the question. I understand it "solved the situation", but it's not what the OP asked. Making graph objects subplots is trivial, making figure factory subplots is a different matter.